# How to split/explode a string by specific characters in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have this string :

```
$str= 'To do list: - Buy milk - Feed cat';
```

How can i convert it to by checking the existence of the `:` and `-` characters

```
To do list:
- Buy milk
- Feed cat
```

I was thinking of creating a reg expression that checks if the string contains `:` or `-` characters and then add a `<br>` tag to each of the matches ..after splitting by those parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to explode, you can very easily convert the input text in the desired format using regex:

```
\s*(-\s*)
```

and replace with **`\n$1`** or (`<br>` instead of `\n` as per your requirement)

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/eT5OYL/1)

Sample code in php using [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$re = '/\s*(-\s*)/';
$str = 'To do list: - Buy milk - Feed cat';
$subst = '\\n$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result; //To do list:\n- Buy milk\n- Feed cat
```

Comment: Thanks - how can i add other characters to the regex? i've tried this "$re = '/\s*(-\s*)+(!\s*)/';" but no good

Comment: what do you mean by other characters? also would be great if you could specify an input and the desired output in that case.

Comment: In your regex you specify it to look only for dashes.... and i want to look for dashes And semicolons ...

Comment: can you give another example of what you want, with **semicolons** and **dashes**? @RoyBarOn

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it with preg_split:

```
$str='To do list: - Buy milk - Feed cat';

$keywords = preg_split("/[-]+/", $str);
```

or

```
$keywords = explode("-", $str);
```

test 1: https://eval.in/893167

test 2 (with explode): https://eval.in/893167

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
$str ='';
$x1 = $x = array();
$str = 'To do list: - Buy milk - Feed cat';
$x  = explode(":",$str);
$x1 = explode(" - ",$x[1]);
echo $x[0];
echo "<br/>";
foreach($x1 as $y){
 echo $y."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `preg_split()` : `preg_split("/[\s,-:]+/", $str)`

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-split.php

The simple `explode()` php method can't do that properly.

Comment: Thanks.. but i wish to explode by more the one parameters.... explode(': / -', $str)

Comment: the explode function can do that. it's just that it needs to be used in a proper way.

Comment: this gives the list of tasks as array : `$tasks = explode("-", explode(":",$str)[1] );`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply using explode function without regex. Here's How

Separate input data into 2 array elements.

```
$x = explode(":",$str);
```

so x is now an array with first element having the text before `:` and second has string containing tasks.

```
$tasks = explode("-",$x[1]);
```

now task is an array with each element containing to do list.

---

or a single line implementation. 
`$tasks = explode("-", explode(":",$str)[1] );`